# Get string values from database without null values C#

Tags: c#, mysql, autocomplete, textbox

in my application i want  to link two textboxes auto complete method with mysql database columns. the first column have 3 values and 2nd column have 7 values.

like this

```
+---------+---------------+--------------+
+appsetid +   category    + subcategory  + 
+---------+---------------+--------------+
+  1      + property pres + Bankruptcy   +
+  2      + attorney      + app          +
+  3      + valuation     + unknown      +
+  4      +  -null-       + mitigate     + 
+  5      +  -null-       + property re  +
+  6      +  -null-       + close        +
+  7      +  -null-       + unk12        +
+---------+---------------+--------------+
```

i wanto to get this column valus as my textbox auto complete values.but after i call below method 1st textbox auto complete get 3 values but second textbox auto complete only complete 1st 3 values. i tried to fill textboxes using isnullorempty,but it's not working

this is my code that i use to fill auto complete of text boxes.

both text boxes Autocompletemode set to suggestappend and autocompleet source set to customsource

```
private void maintxtautocomplete()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection call = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection call2 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    string constring = string.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=claimspro;Uid=root;Pwd=***************;");
    string Query1 = "select * from appsettings ;";
    MySqlConnection conwaqDatabase2 = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase2 = new MySqlCommand(Query1, conwaqDatabase2);
    MySqlDataReader myreader;

    try
    {
        conwaqDatabase2.Open();
        myreader = cmdwaqDatabase2.ExecuteReader();

        while (myreader.Read())
        {
            string sName2 = myreader.GetString("subcategory");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName2))
            {
                call.Add(sName2);
            };

            string sName1 = myreader.GetString("category");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName1))
            {
                call2.Add(sName1);
            };
        }
    }

    catch
    {
    }

    categorytxtbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = call2;
    subcategorytxtbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = call;
    conwaqDatabase2.Close();
}
```

Comment: someone know how to solve this ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solve my problem with wrap my casting method with dbnull if statement

```
 if (myreader["category"] != DBNull.Value)
       {
          string sName1 = myreader.GetString("category");
          call2.Add(sName1);
          comboBox1.Items.Add(sName1);
       };

  if (myreader["subcategory"] != DBNull.Value)
       {
          string sName2 = myreader.GetString("subcategory");
          call.Add(sName2);
          comboBox2.Items.Add(sName2);
       };
```

thanks all who try tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The GetString method will throw an exception when trying to cast a NULL from the database to a string.  So what's happening is that on the 4th record it is falling out to your empty catch.  You need to check if the value is NULL before casting.

You'll want to change your code to something like this:

```
var catValue = myreader.GetValue("category");
string sName1 = catValue == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : catValue.ToString();
```

Comment: this is not working it gave me error like isdbnull does not exists in the current context

Answer (score 0):

I have found using extension methods useful for this:

```
    public static class DataReaderExtensions
    {

            public static string GetStringOrNull(this IDataReader dataReader, string columnName)
            {
                    try
                    {
                            object value = dataReader[columnName];
                            return (value == null || value == DBNull.Value) ? null : (string)value;
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Invalid 'String' data type for column '{0}'", columnName), exception);
                    }
            }

            ...
    }
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
using Extensions; // your extension namespace

string sName2 = myreader.GetStringOrNull("subcategory");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName2))
{
...
```